# Can't play html5 video on page via IIS

Tags: html, iis, video

I'm trying to add training videos to our intra site.  I can't get them to play when I navigate to them "normally" (ie, thru the intra site).  I can get them to play if I access the web page locally.

The file structure is simple:

[image: File Structure]

The code inside Orion.html is fairly simple also:

```
<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: larger;'>Timesheet</span><br><br>
<video width="300" height="200" controls>
    <source src="video\Timesheet.mp4"  type='video/mp4'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

If I navigate to the web page with Windows Explorer, the video works.  However, if I go there via the web ("http://..../Orion.html"), it doesn't work and I get "invalid source".  Our standard is IE, but Chrome has a better debugger and it gave me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I don't manage IIS for our intra...our parent organization does.  Since I couldn't find anything wrong on my end, I contacted them about the problem and received a very long-winded version of "Oh, wow, that sucks for you" as a response.

My questions are:  What's wrong with my code?  If there's nothing wrong with it, is there anything with IIS that might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was IIS.  The MP4 mime type wasn't installed.

Reference:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx